# While executing gem, unknown command

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Whenever I enter a gem command, such as

```
gem "tilt"
```

or

```
gem "mysql"
```

I get this error:

```
While executing gem ... <RuntimeError>
Unknown command tilt
```

When I run `gem list`, both tilt and mysql show up on the list, so they are installed. In fact, I get this error with every item on the list. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`gem` isn't lying to you, they aren't valid `gem` commands.

Perhaps you're confusing the command line with Bundler? For example, adding

```
gem "tilt"
```

to a Gemfile and running `bundle install` will install tilt. But Bundler uses its own syntax, and isn't a shell script. To install tilt using the `gem` binary directly you'd have to do:

```
gem install tilt
```

Running `gem help` will give you a list of `gem`'s command line arguments.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to set mysql to a specific version using the command:  gem 'mysql2', '0.2.7'. Unfortunately, when I use this command, I get the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: Because it's not a valid command as I said. If you read the help documents for `gem` as in my question, as well as `gem help install` for those specific to installing, you'll find the correct arguments for installing a specific version: `gem install mysql2 --version 0.2.7`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Andrew. I got the original command from another stackoverflow page and I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working on my system. I still don't know, but your command does work. Perhaps it has something to do with OS?

Comment: No. As I explained in my answer what you were trying to run is meant to go in a Gemfile used by Bundler.

Comment: Just figured out why. The command "gem 'mysql2', '0.2.7'" is meant for the file Gemfile, not for the command line. For the command line, use Andrew's suggestion: "gem install mysql2 --version 0.2.7"

Answer (score 5):

You're using the Gemfile syntax and you should be using the commandline syntax. Give this a try:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your syntax is correct for more guidelines you can type

`gem help`

To see the acceptable syntax for ruby,

If you get this error "You don't have write permissions for the /Library"

You can always add `sudo` to elevate privileges.

eg. `sudo gem install <gemname>`

Using `sudo` before your code and that will give you administrative access (after you type your computer password).

After that you may have to run `bundle install` to install the gem.