# Jekyll theme could not be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll

Following the jekyll documentation found here: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/ I was trying to install and change a gem based theme so I have chosen the jekyll-theme-primer for this and I've run the following command and instructed under the https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/#installing-a-theme section:

```
gem "jekyll-theme-primer"
```

and got this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command jekyll-theme-awesome
```

After doing some research I've found that I should have added **install** to my query as described here: [While executing gem, unknown command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863576/while-executing-gem-unknown-command)

After running this:

```
gem install "jekyll-theme-primer"
```

I successfully installed the primer gem based theme and got the following confirmation:

```
Successfully installed jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.2
Parsing documentation for jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.2
Done installing documentation for jekyll-theme-primer after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

First question: Was the official documentation incorrect or am I missing something?

I proceeded to run the bundle install command:

```
bundle install
```

and replaced my current minima theme from the _config.yml with the jekyll-theme-primer by adding/replacing this line:

```
theme: jekyll-theme-primer
```

Now when I tried to run either the:

```
jekyll serve
```

or the:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

commands, I get the following error:

```
jekyll 3.5.2 | Error:  The jekyll-theme-primer theme could not be found.
```

So why it can't find the gem theme if the installation was successful?

Comment: To make sure you have the name correct, go to the top of your gemfile and look for which gem host is being used like `source "https://rubygems.org"`. Then you can search rubygems.org for [jekyll-theme-primer](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=jekyll-theme-primer) and get usage info there

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From what I gather, it looks like you did not add `jekyll-theme-primer` to your `Gemfile`, but instead simply executed `gem "jekyll-theme-primer"` in the terminal and later installed the gem correctly after encountering the `Gem::CommandLineError`

So, in short, simply follow the steps below:

- **Add the theme-gem to your `Gemfile`**
- add the theme to your `_config.yml` (correctly done already..)
- Run: `bundle install` (just to make sure Bundler is able to use it)
- Run: `bundle exec jekyll serve`

---

#### Adding a theme-gem to a Gemfile:

Open your current `Gemfile` in a text-editor, and **replace entire line** `gem "minima", "~> 2.0"` with your theme gem. i.e. `gem "jekyll-theme-primer", "~> 0.4"`

Comment: I guess this is where I need help. How do I add the theme-gem to my gemfile? I've followed the instructions for "Add the theme to your site’s Gemfile:" and executed this `gem "jekyll-theme-primer"` but like I said earlier I got this error: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command jekyll-theme-awesome`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! What does the `~> 0.4` stand for and where do I get it?

Comment: The `~> 0.4` stands for the gem version and you can get it from the theme's site or GitHub repo