# Installing Jekyll theme "minimal" leads to error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, themes, jekyll, github-pages

I have tried a few different techniques from posts excruciatingly similar to mine, but nothing seems to work.

I am currently running Jekyll 4.0.0, and I have not even gotten to connecting it to github pages. I'm using a [tutorial by Mike Dane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoRS2D-cyko&t=288s), and I've followed it to the letter. It's an older tutorial so I assume there have been changes.

I have tried reverting to an older version of Jekyll, (3.8.3, as recommended in the post I found) but that gave me more errors than I started with.

Here is my current error as I try to run `bundle exec jekyll serve`

```
jekyll 3.8.6 | Error:  The minimal theme could not be found. Traceback (most recent call last):
        23: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        22: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        21: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        20: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/site.rb:23:in `initialize'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/site.rb:55:in `config='
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in `configure_theme'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in `new'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:12:in `initialize'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:19:in `root'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:82:in `gemspec'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:988:in `find_by_name'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:323:in `to_spec' C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'minimal' (>= 0) among 85 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError) Checked in 'GEM_PATH=C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0;C:/Users/David/.gem/ruby/2.7.0', execute `gem env` for more information
        21: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        20: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/site.rb:23:in `initialize'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/site.rb:55:in `config='
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in `configure_theme'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in `new'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:12:in `initialize'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:19:in `root'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:81:in `gemspec' C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:84:in `rescue in gemspec': The minimal theme could not be found. (Jekyll::Errors::MissingDependencyException)
```

Sorry for the big block, but I'm relatively new and not exactly sure what is important. I have verified from multiple tutorials that I've entered the theme into the gem file properly.

I've installed the gem file using `bundle install' and it properly installed it.

I used `bundle info jekyll-theme-minimal` to install it and have had no luck.

Apologies if there is an identical post to this one, but I have found many with the exact same issue that were solved by something that I had already done. I promise I've searched other posts before making this one.

Note:

Running on Windows 10 Home

gem 3.1.2

ruby 2.7.1p83

doing `jekyll -v` gives an error, which may be part of the same problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380722/jekyll-theme-could-not-be-found/46382649 Maybe this can help, looks pretty same to me.

Comment: @PavelOganesyan This is the main one I was referring to when I said "I have found many with the exact same issue that were solved by something that I had already done."

I've already followed all of those instructions to no avail